# Построение в Python сложной неявной функции с условиями numpy.sign

Tags: python, функции, sympy

Имеется функция типа: F24(x)+k*F23(y) = a
Результатом её построения должна быть кусочно-линейная функция (ломаная линия).
F24 и F23 содержат в себе функции sign (см. фото). С помощью модуля sympy и plot_implicit справиться с построением функции не удалось.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import var, plot_implicit, Eq
beta1 = 0.04
beta2 = 0.3
ksi1 = 0.15
ksi2 = 1.2
ksi3 = 2.5
alfa = 0.4
h = 0.15
k = 2.5


def F23(x, b11, b12, b21, b22):
    return (((x - b11)/2) * (np.sign(x - b11) + 1)) + (((x + b21)/2) * (1 - np.sign(x + b21))) - (((x - b12)/2) * (np.sign(x - b12) + 1)) - (((x + b22)/2) * (1 - np.sign(x + b22)))


def F24(x, b11, b12, b13, b21, b22, b23):
    return F23(x, b11, b12, b21, b22) - ((b12 - b11)/2 * (np.sign(x - b13) + 1)) - ((b22 - b21)/2 * (np.sign(x + b23) - 1))


var('x y')
plot_implicit(Eq(F24(x, ksi1, ksi2, ksi3, ksi1, ksi2, ksi3)+k*F23(y, beta1, beta2, beta1, beta2), alfa))
```

Видимо, implicit совсем не воспринимает sign.

```
D:\Python\python.exe D:/PyProjects/Lamer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PyProjects/Lamer.py", line 22, in <module>
    plot_implicit(Eq(F24(x, ksi1, ksi2, ksi3, ksi1, ksi2, ksi3)+k*F23(y, beta1, beta2, beta1, beta2), alfa))
  File "D:/PyProjects/Lamer.py", line 18, in F24
    return F23(x, b11, b12, b21, b22) - ((b12 - b11)/2 * (np.sign(x - b13) + 1)) - ((b22 - b21)/2 * (np.sign(x + b23) - 1))
  File "D:/PyProjects/Lamer.py", line 14, in F23
    return (((x - b11)/2) * (np.sign(x - b11) + 1)) + (((x + b21)/2) * (1 - np.sign(x + b21))) - (((x - b12)/2) * (np.sign(x - b12) + 1)) - (((x + b22)/2) * (1 - np.sign(x + b22)))
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py", line 229, in __nonzero__
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Подскажите, с помощью чего можно построить подобную функцию?

Comment: Добавьте код и текст ошибки в вопрос **в виде текста**, а не в виде изображения

Comment: Да, точно. Исправил.